# PowerShell - send variable via Invoke-Command

Tags: windows, powershell, server, invoke-command, scriptblock

I have 3 Windows 2016 servers and some routine task I want to automate.
I'm newbie in PowerShell, so I spent a lot of time looking for answer in StackOverflow and "googling".

My task is to backup some files via 7zip on remote server.

There are is a command which works great:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.0.20 -ScriptBlock {start-Process  -wait-FilePath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' -ArgumentList 'a','-t7z','C:\BlueCollar_backup\bluecollar_121.zip','C:\Services\BlueCollar' -wait}
```

But I need to add date to bluecollar_121.zip archive name, it should look like bluecollar_13.08.2018.zip

I've tried a huge amount of variants but with no luck.

```
[string]$stime = get-date -f 'dd.MM.yyyy
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.0.20 -ScriptBlock {start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' -ArgumentsList 'a -t7z C:\BlueCollar_backup\bluecollar_'$stime'.zip C:\Services\BlueCollar' -wait}
```

Second try was:

```
[string]$stime = get-date -f 'dd.MM.yyyy
[string]$tmp1="C:\BlueCollar_backup\bluecollar_$stime.zip"
$command = {start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' -ArgumentsList 'a -t7z $stime C:\Services\BlueCollar' -wait}
```

And the last try:

```
[string]$stime = get-date -f 'dd.MM.yyyy
$arguments = @()
$arguments += "a"
$arguments += "-t7z"
$arguments +=  "$tmp1"
$arguments +=  "C:\Services\BlueCollar"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.0.20 -ScriptBlock {start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' -ArgumentList($arguments) -wait}
```

They all aren't working. The problem is $stime variable.
How can I put variable $stime into Invoke-Command ?

UPD1:
I solved that problem!

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName '10.10.0.20' -ArgumentList  $stime -ScriptBlock{
$stime = $args[0]
start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' "a -t7z C:\BlueCollar_backup\bluecollar_$stime.zip C:\Services\BlueCollar" -wait
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the computer you are executing the command from knows about the $stime variable, but the remote computer doesn't know it.  So you have to pass it in.

There are a couple options, one is to use the $Using variable

```
[string]$stime = get-date -f 'dd.MM.yyyy
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.0.20 -ScriptBlock {
    start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' -ArgumentsList "a -t7z C:\BlueCollar_backup\bluecollar_$($Using:stime).zip C:\Services\BlueCollar" -wait
}
```

Another option that is perhaps a little cleaner looking is to make your ScriptBlock a string of text, and then pass it to the remote computer:

```
$ScriptBlock=[ScriptBlock]::Create("start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe' -ArgumentsList 'a -t7z C:\BlueCollar_backup\bluecollar_$stime.zip C:\Services\BlueCollar'")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.10.0.20 -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
```

An important distinction is between single quotes and double quotes.  When you use single quotes, it resolves text exactly as is.  When you use double quotes, it resolves variables.

Comment: Neither of variants didn't help, there is an error.

Can not find parameter corresponding to parameter name: "ArgumentsList".
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
    + PSComputerName        : 10.10.0.20

Comment: I think it might be 'ArgumentList' instead of 'ArgumentSlist'